# Git clean history and preserve commits after merge

Tags: git, merge, git-branch

In a project our git log was like

```
 1--2--3----------------------------12--        (master)
        \-4--5--------8---9------11-/  \        (branch1)
              \--6-------/---10-/       \       (branch2)
                  \-7-------/            \      (branch3)
                                          \-13  (newbranch)
```

and I want to have :

```
1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8--9--10--11--12--         (master)
                                     \-13       (newbranch)
```

That is to delete all branches but preserve the history and the commits (for further references).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *As I already made changes in a new branch (from master after the 12th commit) I prefer not to have to touch it.* Rewriting history so that it be linear (as you want it) will change the IDs of commits 8-12 and of all the commits that come after that.

Comment: ok, so with changing the commits ID ? question edited

Comment: WHy not just delete branch1/2/3?  What are you trying to gain by making it one line?

Comment: I wanted to clear up the history and delete unused branches (the history is a mess)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make this a comment but I don't have enough reputation yet.  Can you clarify something - are commits 9 through 12 merge commits?  If yes, why would you want to include merge commits in the linear history?  Isn't the point of a linear history to omit merge commits?

Edit:  Regardless, try this:

1)  Figure out the commit hash of commit 1.  Let's say it's 5678.

2)  `git checkout master`.  Then execute `git rebase -i 5678`.  You'll get a prompt.  Reorder the commits 1 through 12.  Then save and exit the editor.

3)  `git checkout newbranch`.  Then execute `git rebase master`.

Rewriting history is always risky, so I'd make sure to have another branch pointing to master before I tried this (origin/master or some other local branch), and that way if things go awry, I can `git reset --hard <pointer-to-previous-master>`.  Same goes for newbranch.

After you're done and everything looks good on master and newbranch, you can delete branches 1-3 using `git branch -D`.

Comment: 9-11 are merge commits but I thought it wasn't useless to include them inside the linear history. I'll try this, I'll let you know.

Comment: seems that your solution worked (even if I got a lot of manual merge to do, Thanks a lot. Have a good christmas !

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git checkout -b new/master 3  (3 should be replaced with the commit sha1 of 3)
$ git cherry-pick 4             (4 should be replaced with the commit sha1 of 4)
$ git cherry-pick 5
$ git cherry-pick 6
...
$ git cherry-pick 12

$ git checkout -b new/newbranch
$ git cherry-pick 13

$ git branch -D master
$ git branch -D branch1
$ git branch -D branch2
$ git branch -D branch3
$ git branch -D newbranch

$ git branch -m new/master master
$ git branch -m new/newbranch newbranch
```

Comment: How to know the order of commits? sorting by date? If so, you can write a little shell script to generate a shell script like this answer.

Comment: I think so, but I wanted to know if it was possible to do it with only a git command or two ...

Answer (score 0):

I created a screencast answering this. Hope it'd help you.

It demonstrates creating a straight Git tree based on a complex one, using SmartGit Git client.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-1u_MTr2Uw

Answer (score 0):

You can check `git log master` and `git log newbranch` - that will **looks** exactly how you want. If you really want to remove all branches and merges and do history plain, it's better to use `git rebase --root master`.